# Align the dropdown list to the right when popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth is FALSE

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning, flex4.5

I have "created" a custom skin for DropDownList (i.e modified the default `spark.skins.spark.DropDownListSkin`) and `spark.skins.spark.DropDownListButtonSkin` for its button.

I have been able to get it to do almost everything I wanted, except for getting the list that drops down to align to the right of the button.  Setting `<s:PopUpAnchor popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth=*false* />` in the button sub-skin allows the list to be determined by the width of the items, because obviously the width of the button/entire control is far less than required.

Here is what it looks like now (default popUpPosition="bottom")

[image: popUpPosition="bottom"]

Setting popUpPosition="right"

[image: popUpPosition="right"]

Here is what I would like it to look like

[image: Imagined "bottom right" alignment]

So at this point, I either need to dig into all the spark source code for DropDownList to better understand how things work, or perhaps someone here knows how to do this already.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom `PopUpAnchor` class which extends from `PopUpAnchor`, and override its determinePosition function to modify how `PopUpPosition.BELOW` behaves:

```
override mx_internal function determinePosition(placement:String,
  popUpWidth:Number, popUpHeight:Number,matrix:Matrix,
  registrationPoint:Point, bounds:Rectangle):void
{
  switch(placement)
  {
    case PopUpPosition.BELOW:
      registrationPoint.x = -popUpWidth + unscaledWidth;
      registrationPoint.y = unscaledHeight;
      break;
    case PopUpPosition.ABOVE:
      registrationPoint.x = 0;
      registrationPoint.y = -popUpHeight;
      break;
    case PopUpPosition.LEFT:
      registrationPoint.x = -popUpWidth;
      registrationPoint.y = 0;
      break;
    case PopUpPosition.RIGHT:
      registrationPoint.x = unscaledWidth;
      registrationPoint.y = 0;
      break;            
    case PopUpPosition.CENTER:
      registrationPoint.x = (unscaledWidth - popUpWidth) / 2;
      registrationPoint.y = (unscaledHeight - popUpHeight) / 2;
      break;            
    case PopUpPosition.TOP_LEFT:
      // already 0,0
      break;
  }
}
```

Setting `registrationPoint.x = -popUpWidth + unscaledWidth` aligns it with the right edge of the button.

Within your `DropDownList` skin replace the `PopUpAnchor` tag with your newly created class and you should have a `DropDownList` which behaves as you requested.

Perhaps there's a saner way of doing this, but I'd rather spend my time not finding out what that is.

Comment: Thanks, quite a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

PopUpAnchor has a property called layoutDirection. I believe that's what your looking for.
If you set that property to "rtl" the dropdown will be aligned as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust [`popUpPosition` of `PopUpAnchor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/PopUpAnchor.html#popUpPosition) in your skin in addition to adjusting `popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth`. It can accept `left` and `right` values. More details is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/PopUpPosition.html).

Comment: Playing with popUpPosition was indeed one of the first things I tried, but unfortunately it does not have any of the options I need; "right" aligns the list to the right, but the anchor of the list is the Top-Left corner, so it comes out all wrong.  I have updated the question to show the results of popUpPosition="right", the first image is popUpPosition="below", the second (mockup) would maybe be "below right" if such a thing existed.